# HTML 5 Validation Error in Visual Studio 2010 MVC 3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, html5-audio

I am confused why Visual Studio 2010 gives me the following Validation error on my source tag.

> Validation (HTML5): Element 'source' cannot be nested within element
>   'audio'

Below is my code in the cshtml View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Audio";
    string audioURL = Url.Content("~/Content/Audio/untitled.mp3");
}

<div>
  <audio id ="myAudio" controls preload="auto">  
      <source src="@audioURL" type="audio/mpeg" />   
  </audio> 
</div>
```

I have been looking around, and I have seen many references to multiple src attributes in the  tag.  But that doesn't answer my question, why the validation error?  Is it actually correct, but VS2010 thinks it wrong, or is it really incorrect, and if so, why is it incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue, it is a bug within Visual Studio 2010, Looking though their docs I found this link
[Web Standards Update for Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/06/15/web-standards-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx?PageIndex=2)

This is what they said about the problem, and the update should fix it.

> The HTML 5 support included in SP1 added intellisense and validation for a lot of new elements such as the video and source elements. However, there were bugs and one of them were the error you would see when adding source elements inside video elements. This is being fixed by this update so you now also get intellisense for the source element.

Comment: It seems the install didn't fix the issue.  But it does seem to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Its the  ~ character in the audioURL string ..

Quoting from similar question on  [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1782459.aspx/1?Validation%20HTML5%20Element%20source%20cannot%20be%20nested%20within%20element%20audio%20)

> ~ character in the src attribute won't be reconginsed in HTML tags!
>
> you cannot use tilder mark to go to the root level unless it's a
>   server control. Use .. to go to the upper directory and so on. That's
>   how you should define the relative path for HTML controls. For
>   example: src="../Mp3/RonaldReaganChallengerAddress.mp3"

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case here.  I don't doubt you're correct about the `~`, but using `Url.Content()` converts the relative path to an absolute, so no `~` is actually being rendered in the html.  The code the op posted would render ` <source src=/Content/Audio/untitled.mp3 type="audio/mpeg" /> `

Comment: Exactly, the rendered line is "/Content/Audio/untitled.mp3" There is no ~.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the source src attribute.  It's already a string

```
 <audio id ="myAudio" controls preload="auto">  
      <source src = @audioURL type="audio/mpeg" />   
  </audio>
```

Comment: The quotes are required if I leave them out then I get a different validation error saying quotes are required. Also the rendered string will not have the quotes. The rendered line looks exactly like what I posted in the comment above.